# Delay markers untill map is fully loaded with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want the Google Map fully loaded before the markers drops in. How can I delay the dropping until the map is fully loaded?

Here is my site; http://dev.askelandmedia.no/2013/index.php